# eosio-cpp -abigen hello.cpp -o hello.wasm

Tags: smart-contract, dapp, eosio.cdt, eosio-cpp

> Ubuntu 18.04.1 on VMware (Windows 10 64bit)
>
> EOSIO v1.4.1
>
> eosio.cdt-1.3.2

i just run the compiler like this :

> win@ubuntu:~/eos$ eosio-cpp -abigen hello.cpp -o hello.wasm

then, the terminal stopped and the compiler created 2 files.

> hello.wasm
>
> hello.wasm.tmpfc9a0c1

because the terminal stopped, i entered ^C.
then, the 2 files changed into :

> hello.abi
>
> hello.wasm

the abi file is good. but wasm file is broken.
of course, i cannot set the contract.

**why doesn't the compiler work properly??**

i use the following hello.cpp code from the eosio.cdt example.

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

CONTRACT hello : public eosio::contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

      ACTION hi( name user ) {
         print( "Hello, ", name{user} );
      }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH( hello, (hi) )
```

Answer (score 1):

solved and it was because of the virtual machine.
https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/issues/123

Answer (score 0):

You should be inside of the contract folder before calling `eosio-cpp`.

Try this:

```
$ cd ~/eos/contracts/hello
~/eos/contracts/hello/$ eosio-cpp -abigen hello.cpp -o hello.wasm
```

Comment: it's not the path problem.
no issue for the compiler to search "hello.cpp".